# How do I bring DRY (don't repeat yourself) in GWT with Java on Appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Frameworks such as Django help to satisfy the DRY principle(don't repeat yourself) for python.

How can I bring the DRY principle in GWT with Java on Google Appengine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that frameworks do that by themselves. They simply provides tools and mechanism that do it.

What I mean is, code GWT stuff until you see code duplications, then seek out specific tools that will help you reduce that redundency. Just don't wait for a "DRY (on/off)" checkbox